# Is there a term which unambiguously refers to both the 32-bit and 64-bit 8086-family ISAs?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, x86

[Wikipedia uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) `x86` to refer to both the 32-bit and 64-bit "instruction set architectures based on the Intel 8086 CPU" (8086-family ISAs). However, often `x86` is used specifically to mean 32-bit (e.g. in `C:\Program Files (x86)`).

There are several other terms which refer specifically to 32-bit (`i386`, `IA-32`) and 64-bit (`x86-64`, `x64`, `amd64`) 8086-family ISAs. Is there a term which unambiguously refers to both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

x86 is a family of backward-compatible instruction set architectures based on the Intel 8086. As noted in the question, x86 can refer to either the 32-bit or the 64-bit architecture, however Windows designates its 32-bit versions as "x86" and 64-bit versions as "x64". This has created a confusing situation for the consumer in which Intel, the processor manufacturer, and Microsoft, the software vendor, use non-matching processor instruction set architecture nomenclature.

In order to provide some help to the baffled consumer, the 32-bit architecture is commonly designated as i386 and the 64-bit architecture is commonly designated as amd64 in the naming of software packages for Linux distributions. An additional advantage of this nomenclature is that it is extensible to include unique names for other processor instruction set architectures such as arm64 and powerpc.